# Rewrite rule doesn't work on joomla htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I need a redirect from http://www.mysite.com/passport/365.html to http://www.mysite.com/passport/365.html?task=view

I try to do it like this
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^/passport/365.html$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /passport/365.html?task=view [QSA]

and it doesn't work.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

try that :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^passport/365\.html$ http://www.mysite.com/passport/365.html?task=view [R]
```

I think in you example ur missing the ****

so it should be something like :

```
RewriteRule ^/passport/365\.html$  /passport/365\.html?task=view [QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use [this plugin](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/url-redirection/14676).

You can simply add the redirect rule to the plugin without modifying .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

There is a component already build in Joomla called "redirect" where U can set-up your redirects, so you don't have to use .htaccess at all.

Here is a good tutorial: http://www.joomtraining.com.au/tutorials/joomla-1.6/creating-a-page-redirect

The problem with the .htaccess is that every redirect must be set in appropriate place in the file.